# How to run selenium java test case and suite using selenium rc through command line

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to run test Suite generated using Selenium ide in firefox through command line in windows OS.

i have created test case and exported as tcjr.java
i have created test suite and exported as tsjs.java

now when i compile test case with:

```
D:\selenium>javac -classpath D:\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-2.40.0.jar D:\selenium\tcjr.java
```

it is compiling and generating tcjr.class
now.. when i compile tsjr with the same command it is showing error:

```
D:\selenium\tsjr.java:4: error: class Tsjr is public, should be declared in a fi
le named Tsjr.java
public class Tsjr {
       ^
D:\selenium\tsjr.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
                suite.addTestSuite(tcjr.class);
                                   ^
  symbol:   class tcjr
  location: class Tsjr
2 errors
```

Please help me in solving this... i am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep the file name and class name same. Only then it will compile. See the first error it shouts that you need to declare Tsjr in Tsjr.java file as oppose to tsjr.java file.

Comment: okay the first error gone but it is showing D:\selenium\tsjr.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
                suite.addTestSuite(tcjr.class);
                                   ^
  symbol:   class tcjr
  location: class Tsjr

Comment: Can you do one thing. Create a project in eclipse IDE. import all those java files, create a lib folder and add all selenium jar files to it. then add all those jar files to classpath using Build Path option in eclipse. And then run your class file from eclipse that should do the trick.

Comment: this will work but i want from command line without eclipse because all jar path i already added in classpath but still it is showing that last error.

Comment: did u check the case. Once it will be worth doing it from eclispe, so that all errors get highlighted upfront. then we can try doing it from command line. i want to make sure all the java files do not have any errors. this is because you are not able to even compile the files.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add reference to all the jar file of whose functionality you want to use in your code. In above case I think you are missing junit reference in classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Keep java file name and class name same as `tcjr.java`

```
public class tcjr {
/*your code here*/
}
```